# Does a pending mean that its execute method has not been called in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Does [status PENDING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html) mean that an [AysncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)'s [execute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) method has not been called?  Or is it possible that it has been called but [doInBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground%28Params...%29) has not been called yet and it is about to be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/AsyncTask.java#AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%2Cjava.lang.Object%5B%5D%29), the task's status is PENDING until `execute()` has been called (line 584).

Comment: the link you supplied is now broken